unable to upload artifacts to nexus through gitlab-ci.yml or from local machine
I'm able to upload artifacts through default method uplaodArchives but I had built in few more custom task to upload artifacts in to nexus through gitlab-ci.yml. Here,
Nexus endpoint accessible from the gitlab & even from Local machine .
Except uploadArchives none the below function are not working

uploadFoRto uploadFoRtf uploadIfCtb uploadIfRto uploadIfRtf

task copyAndRenameWars {
    doLast {
        for (String name : artifactIDs) {
            copy {
                from "$buildDir/libs"
                into "$buildDir/libs/test-${name}"
                include "test.war"
                include "*${name}*.*"
                rename("test.war", "test-${name}.war")
            }
        }
    }
}

task createCustomConfigurationsAndAddArtifacts {
    doLast {
        for (String name : artifactIDs) {
            def folderName = "test-${name}"
            new File("$buildDir/libs/${folderName}").eachFile { file1 ->
                def configName = getConfigurationName(name)
                artifacts.add(configName, file1)
            }
            def configName = getConfigurationName(name)
            configurations.findByName(configName)?.allArtifacts?.each { artifact1 ->
                if (artifact1.type == "jar") {
                    def classifierName = artifact1.name.substring(26)
                    artifact1.classifier = classifierName
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

def getConfigurationName(String artifactType) {
        if (artifactType.equals("if-rtf")) {
            return "ifRtf"
        } else if (artifactType.equals("if-rto")) {
            return "ifRto"
        } else if (artifactType.equals("fo-rtf")) {
            return "foRtf"
        } else if (artifactType.equals("fo-rto")) {
            return "foRto"
        } else if (artifactType.equals("fo-ctb")) {
            return "foCtb"
        } else {
            return "ifCtb"
     }
}

createCustomConfigurationsAndAddArtifacts.dependsOn copyAndRenameWars
build.dependsOn createCustomConfigurationsAndAddArtifacts
clean.dependsOn 'removeBuildFiles'
install.dependsOn build
uploadArchives.dependsOn uploadIfRtf, uploadIfRto, uploadFoRtf, uploadFoRto, uploadIfCtb, uploadFoCtb, ':test-jmx-script:uploadArchives'

def timestamp = new Date().format("yyyyMMdd-HHmmss")
def versionIdWithTimestamp = "${versionId}-${timestamp}"

uploadIfRtf {
  //gradle.taskGraph.whenReady {
    repositories {
        mavenDeployer {
            configuration = configurations.ifRtf
            repository(url: "$nexusUrl/repository/$repo") {
                authentication(userName: System.getProperties().nexusUser, password: System.getProperties().nexusPassword)
            }
            pom.groupId = groupId
            pom.artifactId = project.name+"-if-rtf"
            pom.version = versionIdWithTimestamp         
         }
       }
    //}
}

uploadIfRto {
  //gradle.taskGraph.whenReady {
    repositories {
        mavenDeployer {
            configuration = configurations.ifRto
            repository(url: "$nexusUrl/repository/$repo") {
                authentication(userName: System.getProperties().nexusUser, password: System.getProperties().nexusPassword)
            }
            pom.groupId = groupId
            pom.artifactId = project.name+"-if-rto"
            pom.version = versionIdWithTimestamp         
         }
       }
    //}
}

uploadIfCtb {
    gradle.taskGraph.whenReady {
        //outputs.files("${buildDir}/libs/${project.name}-fo-ctb-${versionIdWithTimestamp}.jar")
    
        repositories {
            mavenDeployer {
                configuration = configurations.ifCtb
                repository(url: "$nexusUrl/repository/$repo") {
                authentication(userName: System.getProperties().nexusUser, password: System.getProperties().nexusPassword)
                }
                pom.groupId = groupId
                pom.artifactId = project.name+"-if-ctb"
                pom.version = versionIdWithTimestamp
            }
        }
    }
}

uploadFoRtf {
  //gradle.taskGraph.whenReady {
    repositories {
        mavenDeployer {
            configuration = configurations.foRtf
            repository(url: "$nexusUrl/repository/$repo") {
                authentication(userName: System.getProperties().nexusUser, password: System.getProperties().nexusPassword)
            }
            pom.groupId = groupId
            pom.artifactId = project.name+"-fo-rtf"
            pom.version = versionIdWithTimestamp           
         }
       }
    //}
}

uploadFoRto {
  //gradle.taskGraph.whenReady {
    repositories {
        mavenDeployer {
            configuration = configurations.foRto
            repository(url: "$nexusUrl/repository/$repo") {
                authentication(userName: System.getProperties().nexusUser, password: System.getProperties().nexusPassword)
            }
            pom.groupId = groupId
            pom.artifactId = project.name+"-fo-rto"
            pom.version = versionIdWithTimestamp
         }
       }
    //}
}

uploadFoCtb {
    //gradle.taskGraph.whenReady {
        repositories {
            mavenDeployer {
                configuration = configurations.foCtb
                repository(url: "$nexusUrl/repository/$repo") {
                authentication(userName: System.getProperties().nexusUser, password: System.getProperties().nexusPassword)
                }
                pom.groupId = groupId
                pom.artifactId = project.name+"-fo-ctb"
                pom.version = versionIdWithTimestamp
            }
        }
    //}
}

uploadArchives {
    repositories {
        mavenDeployer {
            configuration = configurations.deployerJars
            repository(url: "$nexusUrl/repository/$repo") {
                authentication(userName: System.getProperties().nexusUser, password: System.getProperties().nexusPassword)
            }
            pom.groupId = groupId
            pom.artifactId = project.name
            pom.version = versionId
        }
    }
}







task copyTask(type: Copy) {
    from "out/libs/"+ project.name +".war"
    into '../build/libs'
}


**gitlab-ci.yml*


build-gradle:
  variables:
    GRADLE_ARGS: "-x test"
 
gradle-publish:
  variables:
    GRADLE_TARGET: uploadArchives  
    GRADLE_ARGS: "-i"
 
I tried using other subdirectory uploads as well uploadIfRto ..etc

I tired pushing artifacts from local machine like below

./gradlew uploadFoCtb -info

Caching disabled for task ':test:uploadFoCtb' because:
  Build cache is disabled
Task ':test:uploadFoCtb' is not up-to-date because:
  Task has not declared any outputs despite executing actions.
Publishing configuration: configuration ':test:foCtb'
Publishing to org.gradle.api.publication.maven.internal.deployer.DefaultGroovyMavenDeployer@74530508
:test:uploadFoCtb (Thread[Daemon worker Thread 2,5,main]) completed. Took 0.07 secs.
 
BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 5s
1 actionable task: 1 executed


Could some one help me on the above issue
